# I am already logged into Discord, yet it asked me to "claim my account" and then say the email is already registered, how to solve it?

Tags: discord

There are times when **I am already logged into Discord (note: I logged in already)**, with my user name showing at the bottom left of the window, and then I want to join a certain channel.

Then it says at the bottom "You must claim and verify your account" with a "Claim Account" button.  So I thought, I am already logged in with the user name showing, why do I still need to claim my account?

And if I click the "Claim Account" button, and type in my email and password, it'd show an error, "Email already registered" and refuse to go on...  So what is it about and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? It's so terrible.

Comment: @A_P not yet... with all the login system of all websites, this is the *only* one that gives me trouble

Answer (score 1):

1. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
2. Select the **Application** tab
3. Expand **Local Storage** in the **Storage** section on the left, then select **discordapp.com**.
4. Select **token** in the table that was returned and use <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> to delete it.
5. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload the page.

Comment: what magic is that... is it the same if I just use a incognito window or clean all cache for discordapp.com?

Comment: Yes, it sorts the same effect, but stably, without having to resort on an incognito window. It actually fixes your problem. It fixed it in my case (but I use Firefox, so it was a bit different). Just delete cookies (also session) and local-storage for "discord.com" and the temporary account will be gone, you'll be able to login again. I don't know who (wrongly) downvoted the answer.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: The five steps above alone did not work for me so I went back to the **Application** tab and deleted every entry that I saw that mentioned Discord.  Then, I reloaded the page, was asked for my email and password, received an email to authorize my IP address, and was finally able to login and not see the "unclaimed account" message anymore.

Answer (score -1):

you can retrieve the password by:

- Open the Discord app
- Enter your email and click Forgot your password
- Discord then will send you an email with instructions
- Open the email, click Reset Password, and follow the instructions provided.

Comment: It is not to "retrieve" the password.  Please re-read the question.  I am already logged in